# How is it possible to call function from different templates in blazeComponent?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to call a method from different template, for example:

```
class studens extends BlazeComponent {
    average() {}
}
studens.register("templatestudens");

class teacher extends BlazeComponent {
    // how to call templatestudens 'average' function from here?
}
teacher.register("templateteacher");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to define methods in global register helper. Then you can call that method from any template as below;

**CODE for Global declaration for method:**

```
Template.registerHelper("average", function(){
  //code here
});
```

**CODE to call the global helper (in js file)** method from any template

```
Template.YOUR_TEMPLATE.helpers({
  getAverage(){
    return Blaze._globalHelpers['average']();
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, there is no another way of this problem ?

Comment: You can get experts to help you if you raise a bounty, I guess. By far I know this is very much acceptable. And Yes! there can be a expected solution :)